# Xcode C++ header conflicts

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a C++ project that I have split up into a header-only lib (let's call it Alpha) and a dylib (which we can call Delta).
Let's say I have this file hierarchy:

```
Project/
  Alpha/
    include/
      Example_Alpha/
        Alpha.h
        Common.h
  Delta/
    include/
      Example_Delta/
        Delta.h
    src/
      Delta.cpp
      Utils/
        Common.h
```

Example_Alpha/Alpha.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <Example_Alpha/Common.h>

ALPHA_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

class Object {
public:
    virtual ~Object() = default;

    virtual void f() = 0;
};

ALPHA_NAMESPACE_END
```

Example_Alpha/Common.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#define ALPHA_NAMESPACE_BEGIN namespace Alpha {
#define ALPHA_NAMESPACE_END }
```

Example_Delta/Delta.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <Example_Alpha/Alpha.h>

namespace Delta {

class Object {
public:
    Object(Alpha::Object*);
};

} // namespace Delta
```

src/Delta.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Example_Delta/Delta.h>
#include "Common.h"

DELTA_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

Object::Object(Alpha::Object*)
{
}

DELTA_NAMESPACE_END
```

src/Utils/Common.h:

```
#pragma once

#define DELTA_NAMESPACE_BEGIN namespace Delta {
#define DELTA_NAMESPACE_END }
```

The important thing to note here is that there are two separate `Common.h` files and this is what causes my problem. In Xcode I have a target set up to build `Delta.cpp` and I can view `Delta.h`, `Common.h` and `Delta.cpp` in the Project Navigator. However, since Delta depends on Alpha I'd want to be able to view those headers in the Project Navigator as well. But when I drag those files into Xcode it gets confused as to what `Common.h` file it should import when I use `#include "Common.h"` in `Delta.cpp`. It prefers the one from Alpha, which obviously causes errors.

If I move the `Common.h` from `src/Utils` to `src/` it compiles fine, and I guess that's because Xcode first looks for the header in the same directory as the file that includes it. But I want the `Common.h` to be located in the `Utils` folder and other files located in other subdirectories would have the same issue if I just moved it to solve the issue for this particular file.

If I rename the Alpha lib (all file names and code references) to something like Gamma then it works, which makes me think Xcode has an alphabetized list that is the root of the problem. I guess it sees the `Alpha/include/Example_Alpha/Common.h` file before `Delta/src/Utils/Common.h` and it would see `Gamma/include/Example_Gamma/Common.h` afterwards.

These are the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS of Delta:

```
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Alpha/include",
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Delta/include",
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Delta/src"
```

These work fine as long as the headers of Alpha are not added in the Xcode Project Navigator.
I've tried adding `"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Delta/src/Utils"` explicitly as the first one in the list but it does not fix the issue.

I don't think this is related to a specific version of Xcode but I expect it to be the first question. I use Xcode 14.2 on Monterey on the computer where I created the above example.

One thing I think would solve the issue is using a relative header path in the `#include` but I feel that it *should* not be necessary and I really dislike using relative header paths as it adds lots of work when moving a header.

I welcome all ideas, but I would discourage suggestions like "Just don't name a file the same in both libs" or "Just have all source files in the same directory" as they defeat the point of the question. I'm interested in why Xcode behaves this way and what the most practical solution is, without compromising on standards.

Comment: *These are the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS of Delta:* The shown example is not a good practice. Only the `$(PROJECT_DIR)` should be in `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`. All #inlcude should be in the form of `#include "Alpha/include/Example_Alpha/Common.h"`, `#include "Delta/src/Utils/Common.h"`.

Comment: What is the point of those namespace macros?

Comment: @273K I appreciate the thought, but I don't really understand. Can you please elaborate on _why_ it's not good practice? As I understand it you think I should exclusively use relative imports?
@TedLyngmo The point in the example is to give a minimal dependency on those headers. In practice it can serve to increase readability, for example if you simply use `namespace X {` to begin and `}` to end, if there's a lot of code in between then one might wonder what the `}` is tied to, a namespace, a class, it could be anything. This makes it clear what you're dealing with.

Comment: I think your posted question answers your question in the comment. It's not a good practice because file name conflicts are possible, exactly what you have demonstrated in the question post.

Comment: @273K Point taken. What I really wanted to avoid was relative includes like `#include "../../../component/header.h"` since that makes many includes to the same header slightly different. However I realize I can compromise and use relative includes from the base, which makes it easy to change all includes with a single search-and-replace when I move a header.